# Retrieving values from functions located at other components

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So, I'm using the function `getAvailability()` to check the availability of a device. True or False.

I want to retrieve the value generated on the `getEvents.ts` in other components, such as home.ts and use it there. 
In fact i'm checking if it is available or not based on if it's greater than 0.

This is my `getAvailability()` function from the `getEvents.ts`

```
getAvailability(){
     var isAvailable;

    console.log('called getAvailability');

      let availability;
      this.getEvent.getEvent().subscribe(response => {

       let posicao = result;
       if(posicao === undefined){

        console.log('error');
       }else{

        //device
        var device = posicao['value'];


       }

       if(device>0){

        this.isAvailable = false;

      }else{

        this.isAvailable = true;

      }

    });
    console.log(isAvailable);
    return isAvailable;
    }
```

I'm calling it in my home.ts from the constructor, expecting the returning boolean, but nothing happens, just undefined. I've tried a lot and i'm sure i've lost a connection here. If someone would help, I appreciate.
From the getEvents.ts page it logs the value correctly, but when I try to retrieve, it returns undefined.

```
this.getEvents.getAvailability();
```

Can someone help me?

Resuming, I want to retrieve the value from getAvailability function from other files but all I'm being able to do is to call the function, that logs the boolean.

Comment: You need to understand the principle of asynchronism, and to learn how to use observables. This method should not subscribe. It should return an observable. Because that's the only way to return an asynchronous result. You can't ask someone to write and send you an email and expect the email to exist immediately after. You need to start reading the email only when your mail client tells you that the email has arrived. Same here.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @JBNizet! Would this be a good option?  `getAvailability(callback: (data)=> void){}` then retrieve it from my home.ts?

Comment: No. As I said: *It should return an observable*. The controller will then subscribe to the returned observable.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand then, can you explain with code?

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, so I have to guess what it's actually trying to do. But your method would basically look like that: `getAvailability(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getEvent.getEvent().map(event => event['value'] <= 0);
  }`

Comment: Appreciated! Got what you mean now. It works as I was trying to.